# How to merge two dictionaries (defaultdict) that have common keys but different `unique-identifier: list values`?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, defaultdict, dictionary-comprehension

In this given dictionary defaultdict(dict) type data:

Say this is the `dict1`

```
{726: {'X': [3.5, 3.5, 2.0], 'Y': [2.0, 0.0, 0.0], 'chr': [2, 2, 2]}, 128: {'X': [0.5, 4.0, 4.0], 'Y': [4.0, 3.5, 3.5], 'chr': [3, 3, 3]}}
```

`dict2` is

```
{726: {'sum_X': [8, 0, 2], 'sum_Y': [3, 2, 0]}, 128: {'sum_X': [0.5, 2, 0], 'sum_Y': [5, 3.5, 3]}}
```

**Expected output:**

```
Union_dict =

{726: {'X': [3.5, 3.5, 2.0], 'Y': [2.0, 0.0, 0.0], 'chr': [2, 2, 2], 'sum_X': [8, 0, 2], 'sum_Y': [3, 2, 0]}, 128: {'X': [0.5, 4.0, 4.0], 'Y': [4.0, 3.5, 3.5], 'chr': [3, 3, 3], 'sum_X': [0.5, 2, 0], 'sum_Y': [5, 3.5, 3]}}
```

Each dict has a `unique key` (i.e 726, 128...) and are found in both dictionaries (`dict1 and dict2`) but each key in different dictionaries have `unique identifier` with `list values`. I want to merge these dictionaries using the unique keys, **but also want to keep the order of the values inside the list intact and ordered**.

I have tried several methods including the extensive method in [How to merge two dictionaries in a single expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38987/how-to-merge-two-python-dictionaries-in-a-single-expression) explained by `Aaron Hall`. I tried to modify the approaches using what I know about `dict comprehension` but its failing.

I tried:

- 1

  ```
  union_dict = {k: [dict1[i] for i in v] for k, v in dict2.items()}
  ```
- 2

  ```
  union_dict = defaultdict(dict)
  for a,b in dict1.items(), dict2.items():
      union_dict[dict1].append(dict2)
  ```
- 3

  ```
  dicts = [dict1, dict2]
  union_dict = defaultdict(dict)
  for a,b in dicts:
      union_dict[k] = tuple(union_dict[k] for d in dicts)
  ```

Also, can you give me a comprehensive explanation of several ways to do it and **keep the memory footprint low**, since my dictionaries are going to be quite big.

Thanks much !

Comment: `[8, 0, 2}`, is that a typo?

Comment: @Elmex80s: yes it is. its supposed to be `[8, 0, 2]`.

Comment: @TemporalWolf: Sorry if that bothered you. but, I always try to workout the problem myself using what I know, cookbook and old answers on **Stack Overflow**. And, resort to help when the workout deems futile. I hope you understand. Thanks !

Comment: Actually, nothing for my example. These are only `unique identifier` which hold `list values` within the unique `keys`. The keys are same between two dicts but unique identifier arenot. All, I want is the `union using the keys` nothing else, but preserving the order of the list values.

Comment: Based on what I have read, the `update method` should be working but isn't unless I am not understanding it.

Comment: is it guaranteed that no specific key will be in both dicts?

Comment: **keys** will be in both the dictionary but **unique identifier** of the **lists** won't.

Comment: Can you please remove the close flag if anyone did so? It needs one more votes to be closed and I don't want to go through another issue of not having answer or reposting it again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: This solution returns the result as `dict1`:

```
for key, value in dict2.items():
    for subkey, subvalue in value.items():
        dict1[key][subkey] = subvalue
```

by appending all subkeys to `dict1`. If there are conflicts (matching subkeys, `dict1`s will be **overwritten** by `dict2`.

```
>>> dict1
{128: {'Y': [4.0, 3.5, 3.5], 'X': [0.5, 4.0, 4.0], 'chr': [3, 3, 3], 'sum_Y': [5, 3.5, 3], 'sum_X': [0.5, 2, 0]}, 
 726: {'Y': [2.0, 0.0, 0.0], 'X': [3.5, 3.5, 2.0], 'chr': [2, 2, 2], 'sum_Y': [3, 2, 0], 'sum_X': [8, 0, 2]}}
```

If you want to preserve `dict1`, just use [copy.deepcopy()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html#copy.deepcopy) and then add to that new dict.

Comment: This indeed is an simple, elegant and comprehensive. Thanks much !